# Is it possible to embed the properties of one general CSS selector into another more specific class?

Tags: css, embed, css-selectors

I have a general style sheet (general.css) that spans across each page of my site, and more specific style sheets that apply to certain pages. I'd like to take one of the selectors from general.css and embed it into the selectors of my specific sheets.

For example:

(From general.css)

```
.PrimaryFont {
font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", serif; 
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: normal; 
 }
```

(From specific.css)

```
h1 {
   .PrimaryFont;
   font-size: 18pt;
 }
```

This way, I won't have to mark up my html to death, and, if I choose to change the Primary Font, I will only have to do so in one spot.

I know LESS lets you embed, but since I'm new to CSS I was hoping there was some magical way a third party wasn't necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nope. CSS doesn't allow for mixins. You need to use something like LESS/SASS or some other CSS meta framework

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do in plain CSS would be just adding extra classes to elements, but as well as being messy that can quickly get excessive. I would really recommend trying out LESS - it is amazingly good to use.

Comment: Thanks, 46Bit & @Mrchief. If you think LESS is very good, I'll definitely check it out. Seems like it would save a lot of time.